# frame.size does not fit with the iphone simulator spritekit swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator

I just tried to create a Game-Application with Xcode and just went on create new project. As a positioning test, I just wanted to put a Spritenode in the middle of the screen.
I just deleted everything from the Gamescene.Swift and added these three lines:

```
Test = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fail")
Test.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: 
self.size.height/2)
self.addChild(Test)
```

In the simulator, the picture is on the top right corner of the screen, which is very weird - I think.

Xcode Version 9.4.1

[Code and Simulation as a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvjTb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Gameviewcontroller.swift helps my problem.

I just replaced the Code there with

```
let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
let skView = view as! SKView
skView.showsFPS = false
skView.showsNodeCount = false
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = false
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
skView.presentScene(scene)
```